# Can brine springs and creeks be close to each other?

Tags: science-based

Like if there is a mountain that feeds a creek and the creek runs next to a valley that has a brine spring next to it. Is that possible? I’d assume it is since the brine spring needs water from somewhere but I can’t find any information on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mineral springs and surface waterways can get their water differently.**

I was reading about Blue Lick in Kentucky, which looks to have been impressive back in the day.  Big animals from miles around would show up.  People made salt there too.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Licks_Battlefield_State_Resort_Park

But right next to the springs are creeks and there is a big river there too - the Licking river.  The mineral springs are dry now but the river and creeks are fine.  They do not feed the mineral spring and never did.

Rivers and creeks are fresh water.  They are fed by rain and runoff (most of the time; I know a big spring can also be a source).  If you had all this fresh water running thru the mineral spring it would dilute it out and wooly mammoths would lose interest in showing up for a lickfest.  The mineral springs are coming from deep subsurface waters that make their way to the surface.  That is why these springs smell weird, can be carbonated, and sometimes are downright nasty.  Not like good freshwater from a mountain creek.  Alternatively I would rather drink from a spring than from a creek that might have contaminated water.  Water from a spring has been filtered by its long trip underground.

You can have surface waterways like creeks and mineral springs in close proximity.  The stuff coming out of the spring is probably not closely related to or mixed with the water in the creek.